# Undo/Redo editing a DataGridRow

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, undo-redo

If you edit a TextBox you can use Ctrl-Z to undo but in a DataGrid it doesn't work. Is there a way to 'activate' this feature or do I have to write my own undo/redo logic?

Comment: Write your own.  Undo is easy, refresh your data from the server (or many other ways depending on how you are working with data) but redo, that is a little more fun.

Comment: What kind of DataGrid are you using? I've just tried a simple demo with the standard DataGrid, Ctr-Z works normally but of course it requires the current cell to be still in edit mode. Right after committing the data (by typing Enter), you cannot undo it unless you write your own code to support that feature.

Comment: I use the standard DataGrid. Is there a already written, easy to use framework you can recommend?